# Cant rewrite animation for new version of three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new in three.js and docs of it is total mess for me. I found an example of beautiful blob animation and cant rewrite it for new version of three.js.
Here is it
https://codepen.io/aaroniker/pen/YoqNRB

```
let update = () => {

    let time = performance.now() * 0.00001 * speedSlider.val() * Math.pow(processingSlider.val(), 3),
        spikes = spikesSlider.val() * processingSlider.val();

    for(let i = 0; i < sphere.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
        let p = sphere.geometry.vertices[i];
        p.normalize().multiplyScalar(1 + 0.3 * simplex.noise3D(p.x * spikes, p.y * spikes, p.z * spikes + time));
    }

    sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    sphere.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
    sphere.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

}
```

The thing is sphere.geometry.vertices.length in the loop is undefined and example doen't work with latest version of three.js. I know that I can use version like in example, but want a little bit understand it. My discord - pomawewka#0530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like so:

```js
for (let i = 0, element; element = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]')[i++];) {
  rangeSlider.create(element, {
    polyfill: true
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  let speedSlider = $('input[name="speed"]'),
    spikesSlider = $('input[name="spikes"]'),
    processingSlider = $('input[name="processing"]');

  let $canvas = $('#blob canvas'),
    canvas = $canvas[0],
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: canvas,
      context: canvas.getContext('webgl2'),
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    }),
    simplex = new SimplexNoise();

  renderer.setSize($canvas.width(), $canvas.height());
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1);

  let scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, $canvas.width() / $canvas.height(), 0.1, 1000);

  camera.position.z = 5;

  let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.8, 128, 128);

  let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xE4ECFA,
    shininess: 100
  });

  let lightTop = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, .7);
  lightTop.position.set(0, 500, 200);
  lightTop.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(lightTop);

  let lightBottom = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, .25);
  lightBottom.position.set(0, -500, 400);
  lightBottom.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(lightBottom);

  let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x798296);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(sphere);

  const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

  let update = () => {

    let time = performance.now() * 0.00001 * speedSlider.val() * Math.pow(processingSlider.val(), 3),
      spikes = spikesSlider.val() * processingSlider.val();

    const positionAttribute = sphere.geometry.getAttribute('position');

    for (let i = 0; i < positionAttribute.count; i++) {
      vertex.fromBufferAttribute(positionAttribute, i);
      vertex.normalize().multiplyScalar(1 + 0.3 * simplex.noise3D(vertex.x * spikes, vertex.y * spikes, vertex.z * spikes + time));
      positionAttribute.setXYZ(i, vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
    }

    sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true;

  }

  function animate() {
    update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

});
```

```css
#blob {
  position: relative;
}
#blob canvas {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: -7%;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #blob canvas {
    margin-top: -10%;
    width: 800px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #blob canvas {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

.controls {
  background: #3f4656;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px -1px rgba(18, 22, 33, 0.7);
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .controls {
    margin-top: -4%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .controls {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
.controls label {
  color: #cdd9ed;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .controls label {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
}
.controls [type=range] {
  width: 160px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .controls [type=range] {
    width: 280px;
  }
}
.controls > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .controls > div:not(:last-child) {
    margin: 0 0 24px 0;
  }
}

.rangeSlider {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rangeSlider.rangeSlider__horizontal {
  height: 10px;
  width: 160px;
}
.rangeSlider .rangeSlider__fill {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}
.rangeSlider .rangeSlider__fill:before {
  content: "";
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  border: 2px solid #3f4656;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
}
.rangeSlider .rangeSlider__fill__horizontal {
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.rangeSlider .rangeSlider__handle {
  border: 2px solid #3f4656;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.rangeSlider .rangeSlider__handle__horizontal {
  top: -7px;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
*:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Arial;
  background: #1c1f29;
}
body .dribbble {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
body .dribbble img {
  display: block;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.130.1/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://aaroniker.me/range.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplex-noise/2.4.0/simplex-noise.min.js"></script>


<div id="blob">
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <div>
        <label>Speed</label>
        <input type="range" min="10" max="120" value="13" step="1" name="speed">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Spikes</label>
        <input type="range" min=".05" max="2" value=".6" step=".05" name="spikes">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Processing</label>
        <input type="range" min=".6" max="2.4" value="1" step=".01" name="processing">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- dribbble -->
<a class="dribbble" href="https://dribbble.com/shots/6640580-AI-Assistant" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/dribbble-ball-mark-2bd45f09c2fb58dbbfb44766d5d1d07c5a12972d602ef8b32204d28fa3dda554.svg" alt=""></a>
```

The previous geometry format was removed from the core with `r125`. You now have to work with `BufferGeometry`. More information in the following post at the three.js forum.

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401

Comment: You are god! Thanks a lot.

Btw do you know good recourse for three.js learning? Official docs isn't user friendly I think

Comment: Try it with the links from the `Resources` section at the homepage: https://threejs.org/